# How to use Nested foreach loop inside for loop in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, loops, foreach

Hello i want to Generate the View Page like this using looping concept,

```
No CType   PNum
1  Cap     12
2  Bottle  23
```

here is my View Page

```
 @for (int i = 1; i < (Enumerable.Count(@ViewBag.TestComponent_ComponentType)); i++)
            {
                foreach (string component_type in ViewBag.TestComponent_ComponentType)
                {
                    foreach (string part_number in ViewBag.TestComponent_ComponentPNumb)
                    {
                        <td>@i) </td>
                        <td> @Html.Raw(component_type)</td>
                        <td>(Part #:@Html.Raw(part_number))</td>
                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

and here is my controller

```
  ViewBag.TestComponent_ComponentType = context.Test_Component.Where(x => x.TestRequestId == id).Select(x => x.ComponentType).ToList();
  ViewBag.TestComponent_ComponentPNumb = context.Test_Component.Where(x => x.TestRequestId == id).Select(x => x.PartNumber).ToList();
```

please help me.

Comment: And what is wrong with your code? You get any errors?

Comment: No, i am not getting any Error, My code will generate multiple Data, mean          1 CType= 2PNum,

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since both collections are with values from the properties of the same object you don't have to build two collections.
I would suggest you try this:
In your controller:

```
ViewBag.ComponentData = context.Test_Component.Where(x => x.TestRequestId == id).ToList();
```

In your view:

```
@{
     List<Test_Component> compList = ViewBag.ComponentData;
     int count = 1;
 }
 <table>
 <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>cType</th>
      <th>pNum</th> 
 </tr>
 @foreach(Test_Component t in compList)
 {
     <tr>
          <td>@count</td>
          <td>@t.ComponentType</td>
          <td>@t.PNum</td>
     </tr>
     count++;
 }
 </table>
```